# How to reload UITableView without stopping cell selection animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When the users taps on a cell, I want to update my `UITableView`; including the contents of this tapped cell.  Easiest way is to update internal parameters and then invoke `[self.tableView reloadData];`.

However, `reloadData` immediately stops the nice blue->none selection animation of my tapped cell.

Is there a (standard) way to update my table cells without stopping the tapped cell's animation?

Note in this case I don't add or delete cells; I just want to contents to change (e.g. start an activity indicator, or change the color of labels.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can just get pointers to all visible cells and update them.  Something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSArray* visibleCells = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    for (NSIndexPath* indexPath in visibleCells)
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [self updateCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath]; // Your method, which updates content...
    }
}
```

And if you want to update other cells content you can use something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    [self updateCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath]; // Your method, which updates content...
}
```

So your cells will always display correct content.

About creating content:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        [self createContentForCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath]; // so here to create content or customize cell
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks man!  But it does mean moving cell content creation code away from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but that's a good thing anyway.

Comment: usually for performance cell's content creates in cellForRowAtIndexPath method if(cell == nil) {...// here; }. And willDisplayCell method just can update something, for example stop some activity indicator

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you could simply delay the reload of your table data as described for example here: [Delay reloadData on UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328817/delay-reloaddata-on-uitableview)